# Multicol and text background color

Tags: color, multicol

I am searching means to create a `multicol` document in which each column has a background color like illustrated below. The colored areas (red rectangles) should be filled with the background color. Since the document has many columns (4 in the example, but 10 in reality) splitting the text in minipages or similar is not my favored option.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps with `tcolorbox` and it's breakable/magazine features?

Answer (score 3):

If we assume that you are using *unbalanced* columns and want to have the column borders on *all* of the pages of your document, then you can insert them in the background as part of an overlay using [`eso-pic`](http://ctan.org/pkg/eso-pic) (or some other package; there are multiple options):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,multicol}
\usepackage[paper=a3paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{xcolor,eso-pic}
\newlength{\columnwidths}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\columnwidths}{\dimexpr.25\textwidth-.75\columnsep}}
\AddToShipoutPictureBG{% Add to *all* pages in the BackGround
  \AtTextLowerLeft{%
    \hspace{\dimexpr-\fboxsep-\fboxrule}%
    \fcolorbox{red}{white}{\rule{\columnwidths}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\textheight}}% First column
    \hspace{\dimexpr\columnsep-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
    \fcolorbox{red}{white}{\rule{\columnwidths}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\textheight}}% Second column
    \hspace{\dimexpr\columnsep-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
    \fcolorbox{red}{white}{\rule{\columnwidths}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\textheight}}% Third column
    \hspace{\dimexpr\columnsep-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
    \fcolorbox{red}{white}{\rule{\columnwidths}{0pt}\rule{0pt}{\textheight}}% Fourth column
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\sloppy% Just for this example
\begin{multicols*}{4}
\lipsum[1-50]
\lipsum[1-9]
\end{multicols*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can adjust `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule` to suit your needs; the boxes will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks! I have it running for a simple document. For unrelated reasons I need to put the  `multicols` environment into a `minipage`. In this case the rectangles are drawn, but with wrong size and wrong positions, even if the `minipage` covers the whole page. Seemingly some of the length change their meaning ...

Comment: @highsciguy: Well then, I can't do much more without some guidance in the form of a [MWE](http://goo.gl/dtPzv).

Comment: Seems to me the question was how to change the page background color, not to put a colored box around them.  I similarly would like to switch  to \pagecolor{yellow!6!white} adding "yellow pages" starting with the second column on a two-column page.

Comment: @RobRutten: I assume you mean something like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlINt.png)? Here's the [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/i84yMie1).

Comment: @Werner: Yes!  I meant just that.  Works!  I would never ever have come up with such.  Need to specify the flip page number which seems untex-undynamic compared to some command "change background color to this value for this column right here"  but the fact that you solve it this ingenious way suggests it ain't simple.  Thanks!

Comment: @RobRutten: It would be possible to do that, I guess. Write a label to the `.aux` that captures the page number, and then use that page number as the deciding value for where to place the background colour. However, if your text is fairly fixed (not as dynamic), the current hard-coded page-specific solution should suffice, right?

Comment: @Werner: yes, it is fairly fixed and specifying flip(s) is no problem.  Of course now I want more: flip back to white after the yellow.  My current product is https://robrutten.nl/rrweb/rjr-pubs/2021LingAstRep...2R.pdf.   It also strats references in second column.  I tried code sample <somwehere??> but no go.

Comment: @RobRutten: Try [this code](https://pastebin.com/raw/YKeirVeM) where you add multiple condition on the multi-column colouring and have specific left/right colouring for the start/end pages.

Comment: @Werner!  Yes!  Many thanks!  And by now I understand it also (not the same as coming up with it though).